# Is there a way to select a component's prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'll explain better with an example:

```
<template>
    <Comp prop="ex" @click.native="log" />
</template>
```

Having this component in my app is there a way to get the prop value from the script with something like this? (Expecting "ex" to log):

```
<script>
    import Comp from './components/Comp.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            Comp
        },
        methods: {
            log() {
                console.log(Comp.prop)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And if there is a way, does it change when having multiple instances of the same component?

Comment: How about printing the same variable as passed to the component (i.e. `console.log(this.ex)`)?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 It's not a variable but 'ex' string

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 because I have different components with different values of the same prop, and I need the value of the components that I click on

Comment: Since you're already passing in the prop from the consuming component (the parent), you don't need to attempt to access the prop from the child: the prop value is already present in the parent.

Comment: I see the following solutions: Either you store all those `prop` values in a variable and loop them in the template. Then, you have access to the value as variable. Or you define separate variables for all props. Or you just duplicate the value `<Comp prop="ex" @click.native="log('ex')" />`. Or you pass the value to the child and then emit it back to the parent on an event (you cannot use native events for that though).

Answer (score 0):

In this example `prop` prop is hard-coded to be `ex` string. This value is available in `Comp` child but not in the parent. In order to access it in the parent, it should available in parent's state:

```
data() {
  return {
    compPropValue: 'ex'
  }
},
methods: {
    log(value) {
        console.log(value)
    }
}
```

And used like:

```
<Comp :prop="compPropValue" @click.native="log(compPropValue)" />
```

Comment: I can see that working, the problem is that I have different components with different values of the same prop, and I need the value of the components that I click on.

Comment: Consider updating the question with the actual case you have. If these components are siblings then they should be output with v-for from an array, etc. Any way, prop data should be handled in script part of the parent, not template. And you can always duplicate the code and write what the comment suggests, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70723828/is-there-a-way-to-select-a-components-prop/70723980#comment125028123_70723828 , although it doesn't look good

Comment: Thank you, I'm still new to vue and I don't know what are the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

It just occurred to me that I can simply pass the value that I need as a parameter of the function:

```
<template>
    <Comp prop="ex" @click.native="log("ex") />
</template>

<script>
    import Comp from './components/Comp.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            Comp
        },
        methods: {
            log(s) {
                console.log(s)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If someone knows how to actually do what I wanted it would still be helpful though!